# List won't bring up definition when item is clicked on

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've started learning how to code and am currently learning basics in python. I've been trying to get a small to do list app to work and bring up descriptions when i click on list items but it comes up "no attribute description". Can someone show tell me what i'm missing in my code?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import BOLD
import tkinter as tk


class ToDoItem:
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name= name
        self.description = description

class ToDoListApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("To Do List")
    
        frame = Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief=SUNKEN)
        frame.grid(column=1,row=1, sticky= (N, E, S, W))
        root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        list_label= Label(frame, text='To Do Items')
        list_label.grid(column=1,row=1, sticky=(S, W))
        
        self.to_do_items = [
            ToDoItem('cleaning','laundry,dishes,sweeping'),
            ToDoItem('job','coding, dashing, bills'),
            ToDoItem('self_care', 'bubble bath , manicure, sleep'),
            ]
        
        self.to_do_names =StringVar(value= list(map(lambda x: x.name,self.to_do_items)))
        items_list= Listbox(frame, listvariable=self.to_do_names)
        items_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',lambda s: self.select_item(items_list.curselection()))
        items_list.grid(column=1,row=2, sticky= (W, E), rowspan=5)
        
        self.selected_descriptions =StringVar()
        selected_descriptions_label = Label(frame, textvariable=self.selected_descriptions, wraplength=200)
        selected_descriptions_label.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=(E, W))

        #New ITem

        new_item_label= Label(frame, text="new item")
        new_item_label.grid(column=2,row=1, sticky=(S,W))

        name_label= Label(frame, text="item name")
        name_label.grid(column=2,row=2, sticky=(S,W))

        self.name= StringVar()
        name_entry=Entry(frame, textvariable=self.name)
        name_entry.grid(column=2,row=3, sticky=(N,E,W))

        #Description/Definition

        description_label= Label(frame, text="item description")
        description_label.grid(column=2,row=4, sticky=(S,W))

        self.description=StringVar()
        description_entry=Entry(frame, textvariable=self.description)
        description_entry.grid(column=2,row=5, sticky=(N,E,W))

        save_button= Button(frame, text= 'save', command=self.save_item)
        save_button.grid(column=2,row=6, sticky=(E))

    def save_item(self,):
        name= self.name.get()
        description =self.description.get()
        new_item=ToDoItem(name,description)
        self.to_do_items.append(new_item)
        self.to_do_names.set(list(map(lambda x: x.name,self.to_do_items)))

    def select_item(self, index):
        selected_item =self.to_do_items[index[0]]
        self.selected_descriptions.set(selected_item.descriptions)

root = Tk()
ToDoListApp(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. It sounds like `selected_item` is not a `ToDoItem` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo.
You wrote

```py
def select_item(self, index):
   selected_item =self.to_do_items[index[0]]
   self.selected_descriptions.set(selected_item.descriptions)
```

and the error you got is

```
AttributeError: 'ToDoItem' object has no attribute 'descriptions'
```

Thats because the ToDoItem class has the attribute **`description`** and not **`descriptions`**.

Remove the **`s`** and you're done.

```py
def select_item(self, index):
   selected_item =self.to_do_items[index[0]]
   self.selected_descriptions.set(selected_item.description)
```

Comment: You should have tagged the question as a typo and left a comment, not posted an answer to that effect.